# long n = 922337203685477580; – почему ошибка?

Tags: java, syntax

```
long n = 922337203685477580;
```

Ошибка: integer number too large. Но при чём здесь integer если я указываю тип long?

Comment: Видимо Java ведет себя как С и С++. Что вы там указали в левой части не имеет никакого влияния на интерпретацию правой части.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы тип переменной указываете `long`, а литерал у вас остаётся типа `int`. Исправить можно добавлением спецификатора

```
long n = 922337203685477580L;
```